# Environment that does not display in handout mode in beamer

Tags: beamer, environments

Using beamer, I want to define an environment that does not display in `handout` mode. I would such an environment both because it gives my documents a better structure and because it is easier to put large chucks of material into an environment than using something like  `\only<handout:>{...}` multiple times.

My first thought was to try:

```
\newenvironment{Lecture}{\actionenv<handout:0>}{\endactionenv}
```

In `handout` mode this does exactly what I want. In `beamer` mode, this works well most of the time but it does not do what I want when the `Lecture` environment contains material that should be displayed on "earlier" slides. For example, consider:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[]{xparse}
\newenvironment{Lecture}{\actionenv<handout:0>}{\endactionenv}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{A frame}

    First slide

    \pause second slide

    \begin{Lecture}
      \only<1>{First slide..lecture}

      Second slide..lecture

      \pause Third slide..lecture

    \end{Lecture}

    \pause[3]Third slide
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Working frame}

    First slide

    \pause second slide

      \onslide<1 | handout:0>{First slide..lecture}

      \only<handout:0>{Second slide..lecture}

      \pause[3]\only<handout:0>{Third slide..lecture}

    \pause[3]Third slide
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Notice that the text "First slide..lecture" never appears --- even on the second slide, which is supposed to show what I want. I have tried variants using:

- `\newenvironment{Lecture}{\onslide<handout:0>}{}`
- `\newenvironment{Lecture}{\only<handout:0>}{}`
- `\NewDocumentEnvironment{Lecture}{ d<> }{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\onslide<1-| handout:0>}{\onslide<#1| handout:0>}}`

Nothing that I have tries gives me what I want.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't use beamer often, but I tried your example by deleting the first frame and commenting out the definition of Lecture environment. The line containing `First slide ... lecture` still does not appear. So, this has nothing to do with your definition of the Lecture environment.

Comment: I am not sure, It may works: `\only<handout:0>{First slide..lecture}` instead of `\only<1>{First slide..lecture}` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with your definition but with your use of `\pause`.  Commenting out the `Lecture` environment from your first slide still does not show the `\only<1>` text, because the previous `\pause` command prevents that being read.  Instead the first `\pause` can be replaced by `\onslide<2->{...}` or similary and a later `\pause`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[]{xparse}
\newenvironment{Lecture}{\actionenv<handout:0>}{\endactionenv}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}

  First slide

  \onslide<2->{second slide}

  \begin{Lecture}
    \only<1>{First slide..lecture}

    \pause Second slide..lecture

    \pause Third slide..lecture
  \end{Lecture}

  \pause[3]Third slide
\end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Working frame}

    First slide

    \pause second slide

      \onslide<1 | handout:0>{First slide..lecture}

      \only<handout:0>{Second slide..lecture}

      \pause[3]\only<handout:0>{Third slide..lecture}

    \pause[3]Third slide
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Lecture slide 1

[image: Sample lecture slide]

### Handout page 1

[image: Sample handout page]